# How to resolve Excel IF AND question query formula

Tags: excel, if-statement

Need help with a Excel formula.
I have two sets of data in two tables, with the same number of columns and rows.
One table has data for male, the other one for female.
Each table has a common definer (age). All the other data are different. All data are in numbers. Some are negative.

I aim to use a single cell to get a result coefficient used by a specific equation, and I need to channel the input data by two criteria. One is gender, the other one is age. I am trying the IF AND formula, but it is not working.

Here is an example.

```
age (D2)          coefficient (D2-D4)
Table Female.
18-30 yrs     25
30-60 yrs     35
60-70 yrs     41
```

So here is the data to process:

```
D1 F
D2 29
D3 115
```

(MEANING Gender - female; age 29; weight 115 pounds)

I was trying the IF AND formula

```
=IF(AND(D1="F";D2>17;D2<30);(D3+H2);IF(AND(D2>=30;D2<60);(D3+H4)))
```

Now, this works fine when I only calculate the female data, but I can't seem the find the way to include the formula to choose from the MALE table, if the subject is male ("M").
Any help or clues on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.  It would be easy to help you if you paste a screenshot of your table etc as it would make us understand your problem clearly.
Anyway, two solution advice from me:
1- you can use nested `if` operators but not like yours.  Before expressing conditions with `and` operator, add another `if` to start processing data related to females. Like this: `=IF(D1="F";IF(AND(D2>17;D2<30);(D3+H2);IF(AND(D2>=30;D2<60);(D3+H4)))`.
After processing females, add the same formula strings this time for males. This will solve your puzzle I guess.

2- my second advice would be creating a user-defined function.  I often create a user-defined function if my formula gets too long and become hard to read.  I strongly recommend you to search for this as it will make you better-understand the logics in excel functions and make you equipped against your puzzles in future.

Comment: Even better than a screenshot would be a google doc or similar with some representative data.  That way not only could we see it, but we could copy the data out easily.